# SWT/JFace - Customize Menubar on OS X - How?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swt, jface

So there is that silly default top bar with JFace/SWT applications.
Dropdowns do nothing, it does nothing.

I want to customize it as in actually give it some purpose.
Found [this tutorial](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/19/configuring-the-os-x-application-menu-for-swt-apps/) and it looked just great.

The problem is that I can't find that package.
It says:
*...we copy the following files from* **org.eclipse.ui.cocoa** *into our project:*

I looked on both Eclipse packages (Win/Mac) but there is nothing.
Tried to check the files too which it mentions later on, but no luck either.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.eclipse.ui.cocoa` is not in the Eclipse 4 release as Mac support has been reworked. You can find it in Eclipse 3.8.2 available here: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Comment: Okay okay. So if it's got "fixed up", is there an internal way to do this instead of copying around files from packages? I doubt this is the proper way of doing this... Or is it?

Comment: I don't know, I write Eclipse RCP apps where all this is is handled for you. Changed tags to include swt as some of the people who watch swt may know.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try this when I get to my project. If it works, I'll accept it as an answer. (Shame on Eclipse though.)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround, not the answer:

The tutorial didn't work, nor the copy-in method.
But! You can use this: `Display.setAppName("Foo Strikes Back 4");`

And then the menu bar will have this name at top-left.
It's not that great, and you can't customize what Exit does and so on, so it's just more of a workaround.